# How can i collect aws rds instances actions list

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, automation, boto3, amazon-rds

I am unable to get the following details in boto3 for AWS RDS:

[image: Actions list]

I tried using below code to get these details:

```
paginator = rds.get_paginator('describe_pending_maintenance_actions')
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are `RDS Recommendations` and not `Pending Maintenance Actions`.

**Recommendations** are AWS best practices. And unfortunately, it seems there's no API for viewing `RDS Recommendations`.

The documentation doesn't mentioned any API or CLI commands for it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/accessing-monitoring.html#USER_Recommendations

**Pending Maintenance Actions** are action such as OS update. You can view it from the console under `Maintenance & Backup` tab when you select a Cluster or Database.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.html#USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Maintenance.Viewing